Knapsack problem with at least 1 item of two categories, no boundary on total items, unique items
Let's say we want to maximize the caloric intake of a person. One person MUST pick AT LEAST ONE steak and AT LEAST ONE vegetable (no limit of how many steaks or veggies he can pick, as long as they are under 50 USD). Each steak is unique in terms of weight and price, same applies for the vegetables. i.e. we have steak1 10 usd, 500 calories, steak2 15 usd, 300 calories, vegetable1 2 usd, 50 kcal, vegetable2, 3 usd 55 kcal, etc.

Said. Now what is your answerable CS question about this?

A simple, straight-forward approach is as follows: Suppose there are $m$ steaks and $n$ vegetables. Create $m\times n$ pairs of these items. For each of these pairs, take the pair into the solution, adjust the remaining budget, and then solve the normal knapsack problem on the remaining items. Finally, take the maximum among these $m\times n$ solutions.

@greybeard, USD values will work as weight bounds and calories as profits in the case of applying classical knapsack.

(missed the and then part - too bad the vote is locked)

@greybeard, no worries :)
